# Problema procedimiento almacenado en mariaDB con filtros

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mariadb

tengo una inquietud, resulta que desde una consulta normal obtengo datos de usuarios y los filtro por su estado y un rango de fechas con un WHERE como enseño a continuación:

```
SELECT id,nombre,fecha 
FROM users
WHERE estado = 'Activo' 
AND str_to_date(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-12-31"
```

Como se observa estoy realizando un cambio en el formato de fecha con el **str_to_date** ya que en la tabla la guardan con el formato **d/m/y**.

Cuando ejecute la consulta todo funciona normal, pero resulta que para tareas mas especificas lo implemente en un procedimiento almacenado, de la misma forma, tal cual copie y pegue, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me saca un error por que algunos campos están errados en el formato de la fecha, entendería que por el formato se pueda presentar este error pero sucede que este error esta en los campos que contienen el estado inactivo y en mi filtro solo traigo los activos y aparte tomo como rango el año 2021 pero el error es de una fecha del año 2020.

Mi gran inquietud es por que en una consulta simple funciona sin problema pero en el procedimiento almacenado me salta el error, como si el procedimiento también leyera los campos de los registros con estado inactivo sin respetar mi filtro.

Este es el error que sale en pantalla: Incorrect datetime value: '06/14/2020' for function str_to_date

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=92a72c35bcc8cf6f55fbf9c1e52ddef6).

Answer (score 0):

Por el formato que aportas como ejemplo `06/14/2020`, deberías modificar:

```
str_to_date(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Y poner en su lugar

```
str_to_date(fecha, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Prueba y me comentas qué tal

Comment: Muchas gracias David, esto me funciono, saludos.

Comment: Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)